# How do I identify where colors comes from?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, sitepages, theme

We have a section on a page that follows colors from theme. I am trying to figure out how to change that color. It seems like it comes from a style called `.root-138`.

Any suggestions to trouble shoot how to change that specific color in the theme?

[image]

Comment: Those colors are coming from theme. Please follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-powershell) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview) link which describes how to create custom theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint default themes, you cannot change specific color in the theme for specific SharePoint site by using SharePoint OOTB capabilities.

It is better to create your own custom theme which suits your requirements.

Check below Microsoft official documentation to create custom themes:

1. [SharePoint site theming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview)
2. [SharePoint site theming: JSON schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-json-schema) - You can get JSON schema for default themes here. You can use it to create a new custom theme by changing specific colors as per your requirements.
3. [Fluent UI Theme Designer](https://fluentuipr.z22.web.core.windows.net/heads/master/theming-designer/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. I all ready used all that. My problem is to identify what styles in the json, is doing what. As an example the color in the section you see in my image. Why does that follow the current theme? A style called root-138. How does that apply with the josn classes? I can see when I change theme it changes color. So it must be connected to the theme somehow.

Comment: Which theme you have used? Can you add theme JSON schema/colors to your question?